# Web page with script

Tags: ffmpeg

please be patient with me, I have never been very much into the coding (only at the university just a little) but here is one thing I would love to have. I havent done any research before asking before I dont even know what to search for :) but here is what I would like to do:

I have synology device with multicast TV stream connected to it. I have installed ffmpeg and everytime I want to record a TV show I have to do it from CLI so I was thinking it would be nice to run this ffmpeg from the web page. I mean I would click the TV channel from the drop down menu, set the name of a file, set the time and click RUN and then the command (ffmpeg -i http://MULTICAST_STREAM-variable -acodec copy -vcodec copy /var/services/homes/xxx/NAME_OF_TV_SHOW.mpg) will execute on my synology...Is something like this possible? (I hope it is)...What exactly should I search for?

Thank you very much

Comment: Very broad, but anyways... VLC player can do just that too.

Comment: hi, I had a problem to install VLC on synology and I do not want to brick the synology since I dont have direct access to it and I do not want to record it with VLC on a client PC. So thats the reason why the web page would be the best option. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Should not add that functionality in a script in the webpage, because if browser is closed the conversion process would fail. Better setup something similar to this:

1. A service that monitors a transforming queue in the NAS and if file changes launches the ffmpeg process.
2. A browser plugin (permission issues in the filesystem?) or a desktop app that inserts in the queue file the job (url & name of the show).

Some time ago I did something very similar using c# (the second part was a transmission download folder monitoring service). Be wary that those NAS usually have not decent CPU's and could be problematic and consider doing that process on better hardware. You can check it searching for 'ffmepgconverter' on codeplex.

Comment: hi, the hw performance is not a problem since there is no transcoding of the video stream. It only saves the stream on HDD. The plugin and desktop app is not good for me. I would prefer the web page. So if the web page insert a process on a synology and then I close the web page, then there is a possibility that the process would end? thank you

Comment: It would not insert the process, it would send a command to order the NAS start thr process (via a file being monitored, creating a webservice that the webpage would consume, however you make it). The important thing is not to start the process on the webpage, but on the NAS.

Comment: hi, yes. sounds good. no the important question is, how to do it :) what should I search for? is it too complicated? thank you

Comment: reuse my code, the project name is ffmpegconverter and it is located on codeplex :-) The only requirement would be installing mono in the sinology